# Compare num records returned to a set integer and display message if true

Tags: php, mysql

How to compare number of rows returned to a number and display message

I have a form with a drop down where people can select either a serial number or the name of a product and a textbox where they can type their search. I have the minimum length set to 1 because the serial numbers are minimum 1 digit and range up to 5 digits. Also, so that if they only know the first letter of the name it lists all the records starting with that letter. If they type the name of the product and only know the first letter of it, I'd like to display a message if they only type one letter in the name that says something like "Please try typing more than one letter." I can succesfully display this message, but if the number of records return is less than 5 it still displays.

I wrote code on the processing page for the form, so that it counts the number of rows returned and checks to see if it is greater than or equal to 5. I wanted to display this message if the search returns more than 5 records.

My question: How do I compare the number of records returned to the set number of 5 so that my message to go back and try a longer search (for the name of product) displays only when there are 5 or more records returned? It seems to display the message fine, but when <5 records are returned, it still displays the message.

my code processing page PHP code:

```
include "includeData.php";

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $mysqlUname,$mysqlPW, $mysqlDB);
if (!$conn){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!empty($_GET['searchText'])){
$query = $_GET['searchText'];

$min_length = 1;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$query);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM machine WHERE `m_ipdb` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `m_name` LIKE '%". $query."%'";

    $qResults = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if (!$qResults){
            echo "There was a problem!<br />";
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
            //added for best practice and consistency
        }

        echo "<table border='1'>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qResults))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['m_ipdb'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"details.php?m_ipdb=" . $row['m_ipdb'] . "&m_name=" . $row['m_name'] . "\">";
                echo $row['m_name'];
                echo "</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";


    /*echo "<p>Number of rows returned: " . mysqli_num_rows($qResults) . "<br />";*/



    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM machine");
    $num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count = $num["number"];

    if($count >= 5){
        echo "<a href='search.php'>Return to Search Page</a><br />" . "And try searching for more than one letter in the name!";
    }
    else{
        echo " ";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}


}
```

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and has likely already been compromised.  Never concatenate arbitrary data into the context of an SQL query.  Always use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem.  Additionally, never concatenate arbitrary data into the context of HTML without escaping it!  You risk creating invalid HTML, as well as script injection and security issues.  Finally, you haven't escaped anything for use in the query string you're echoing out either.  These are serious issues  you should address immediately.

Comment: my code is running on a test server, virtual test server on a friend's machine so I'm sure it hasn't been compromised. but thanks for the advice.